# Disable Cache in Chrome Developer Tools Not Working

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, disable-caching

The "Disable Cache" option in Chrome Developer Tools stopped working about a week ago (Mid February 2021).

Is anyone else having this problem and is there a fix for it?  I mean a browser fix. I already know how to "Trick" a browser into reloading resources, but Disable Cache was working fine until recently and is the simplest, preferred solution.

I can't recall having changed anything browser or network related. It just suddenly stopped working.

UPDATE APRIL 2024: It happened again but I have found this has nothing to do with Chrome disable cache.  The 1st clue was that disable cache is working for another site hosted on a different web host.  The 2nd clue and confirmation is that I created a new file on the problem host and it is not there (404 not found.)  So this means that my client's web host is serving an old files 'Snapshot' and I will have to check back and see when the files are updated.  Dreamhost and Bluehost have been the problem hosts.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/213237860?hl=en&msgid=213238050) below on [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome), you cannot disable cache on Google Chrome even if turning on **Disable cache** in **Network** on Developer Tools. *I experimented it with Google Chrome and Firefox by myself, then both cannot disable cache:

> You can't disable cache due to performance problem. It is same problem on other browser such as FireFox, Chromium, Brave, Opera.

So every test on Google Chrome, you need to clear cache following [the doc](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). *You can open the page to clear cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which also works on Firefox. Or you can empty cache and reload the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox). Or you can use the Google Chrome extension [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) to clear cache.

Comment: solved such an annoying problem thank you with that clear cache recommendation!

too bad it's your whole browser but super important when doing dev in your preferred browser

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a general problem with cache control. You can see my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67366558/4489551, and I hope it will help you.

Comment: So the problem went away on its own after 2 days.  I dont believe in glitches, but I think thats what this was because as mentioned I changed nothing in .htaccess or headers anywhere when the problem started.  I appreciate your answer and maybe it will help other people in same situation..

Comment: UPDATE: Friends, it happened to me again.  Chrome Developer Tools "Disable Cache" is not working for *one* client website.  That is a new clue!    Also, client has both of them are hosted on Bluehost.   Disable Cache works for one but not for the other.  Its been 4 days and Disable Cache still does not work for that other site.